# multiple jquery galleries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to separate two jQuery galleries, so they don't interlink on my html page:

http://mashanova.com/myFAQ/faqGallery.html#

here is the html:

here is javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('.gallery_thumbnails a').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();


        $('.gallery_thumbnails a').removeClass('selected');
        $('.gallery_thumbnails a').children().css('opacity','1');

        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(this).children().css('opacity','.4');



        var photo_fullsize = $(this).attr('href');
        var photo_preveiw = photo_fullsize.replace('fullsize','preview');


        $('.gallery_preview').html('<a href="'+photo_fullsize+'" style="background-image:url('+photo_preveiw+');"></a>');


    });


});
```

Comment: I think you'll have to cough up a little more than this ?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the galleries to work as 2 independent entities?  If so, you'll need to give id's to the galleries.  Right now you have one function that is manipulating classes - which means it will do the exact same thing with every item that has that class.